# Jquery Multiple Selectors with attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I would like to select elements using Jquery. I have two patterns - **input[aria-invalid='true']** and **select[aria-invalid='true'**]. How can I write those two patterns in one Jquery selector?

Comment: Assuming you want the union of the elements: $("input[aria-invalid='true'],select[aria-invalid='true'])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by

```
$("input[aria-invalid='true'], select[aria-invalid='true']")
```

For reference - https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/